# PayPal Invoicing API error ID 580001

Tags: paypal

The example call in the PayPal Invoicing API [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/invoicing/gs_Invoicing/) is returning an error?

**Request**

```
curl -s --insecure -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: caller_1312486258_biz_api1.gmail.com" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 1312486294" -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: AbtI7HV1xB428VygBUcIhARzxch4AL65.T18CTeylixNNxDZUu0iO87e" -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON" -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:APP-80W284485P519543T" https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Invoice/CreateAndSendInvoice -d {\"requestEnvelope\":{\"errorLanguage\":\"en_US\"},\"invoice\":{\"merchantEmail\":\"caller_1335455804_biz@x.com\",\"payerEmail\":\"sender_1335455648_per@x.com\",\"currencyCode\":\"USD\",\"paymentTerms\":\"DueOnReceipt\",\"itemList\":{\"item\":[{\"name\":\"BananaPlant\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"unitPrice\":\"38.95\"},{\"name\":\"PeachTree\",\"quantity\":\"2\",\"unitPrice\":\"14.95\"}]}}}
```

**Response**

```
{"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2013-08-22T23:58:47.340-07:00","ack":"Failure","correlationId":"4838886d6636b","build":"7236486"},"error":[{"errorId":"580001","domain":"PLATFORM","subdomain":"Application","severity":"Error","category":"Application","message":"Invalid request: {0}"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the payload in the -d switch within "". Running the curl snippet with the -v switch as-is will show you that the payload gets truncated and hence the "Invalid request" error.

Also, you will see a "Invalid token" error when the merchantEmail in the request is not the same as the API caller. If you need to generate invoices on behalf of a third party (in which case the API caller and merchantEmail are naturally different), you must obtain [third party permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/) and attach a X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header to your request.